# Errors in tutorial project from Unreal's documentation

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm trying to learn C++/UE4 for the first time, and the code provided in the tutorial (in their own documentation) throws errors. How can I fix this and/or find a tutorial that works?

I'm attempting to work through the tutorial at https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/Tutorials/PlayerInput/index.html, but the code provided in Step 1 throws errors.

I have tried the 'potential fixes' and looked around online but haven't found anything to fix the error.

AMyPawn::AMyPawn()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

```
// Set this pawn to be controlled by the lowest-numbered player
AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

// Create a dummy root component we can attach things to.
RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
// Create a camera and a visible object

UCameraComponent* OurCamera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("OurCamera"));
OurVisibleComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("OurVisibleComponent"));
// Attach our camera and visible object to our root component. Offset and rotate the camera.
OurCamera->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
OurCamera->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(-250.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f));
OurCamera->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(-45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
OurVisibleComponent->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
```

}

Error C2065 'UCameraComponent': undeclared identifier

Error C2065 'OurCamera': undeclared identifier

Error C2672 'UObject::CreateDefaultSubobject': no matching overloaded function found

Error C2974 'UObject::CreateDefaultSubobject': invalid template argument for 'TReturnType', type expected

Error   MSB3075 The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.22\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" SecondUnrealProjectEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users...\SecondUnrealProject\SecondUnrealProject.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.

I expected the code to run without errors as I am following the tutorial exactly (and have in fact copy-pasted the 'working' code to check that I didn't change anything by accident)

Comment: *"If you are new to Unreal Engine 4, you might want to read our Programming Quick Start tutorial first. For this tutorial, we will assume you are familiar with creating a project, adding C++ code to it, and compiling your code."* <- Have you done that?

Comment: This looks like a reasonably obvious error, you'd need to include the file containing `UCameraComponent`. I'd go as far as to say that unreal development without some prior c++ knowledge or better yet experience, will be no fun. Have a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). There's also video tutorials and things like udemy courses, though I've heard finding a good and complete one may be tricky ( but that's just heresy, might be tons of gooduns if you prefer video learning).

Comment: Yeah I did their first tutorial already. This is the second one. I'm still learning the basics, but its hard when the code the tutorial provides doesn't work.

Comment: @George

I figured it would be something obvious, but the tutorial doesn't even suggest including anything that I haven't already done. Unfortunately I don't really have the time or the money to order any books :(

Comment: Yup, just tried that code and can confirm it's missing an include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error means that the compiler can't find the declaration for `UCameraComponent`, the other errors are simply follow-up errors.

You need to add the following include to your `MyPawn.cpp`:

```
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
```

After fixing that you'll get another error, this time because the declaration for `UStaticMeshComponent` is missing. For that you need the following include:

```
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
```

The error messages are different, because in the first case the compiler wants to instantiate an object of an unknown type, which is not possible, while in the latter case the compiler wants to assign a pointer of the unknown type `UStaticMeshComponent` to another pointer of the known type `USceneComponent`, and it doesn't know that `UStaticMeshComponent` can be cast to `USceneComponent`.

I agree that it's bad that the tutorial missed this, however finding a missing include is fairly easy with the right tool. In Visual Studio you can simply click on any type (e.g. `UCameraComponent`) while holding `Ctrl` and it will either directly go to the declaration, or it will show you a list of files with potential declarations.

In Unreal it's also generally the case that for every component the include file has that component's name, so for `UCameraComponent` that's `CameraComponent.h`, which resides in the subfolder `Camera`.

Comment: Mate you're an absolute legend

Comment: Only issue now is that I'm still getting 'a value of type " UStaticMeshComponent * " cannot be assigned to an entity of type " USceneComponent * " '. Do I fix that by changing USceneComponent (in the MyPawn.h) to UStaticMeshComponent, vice versa or do ignore the error? (it's displayed at the bottom of the window and a red line appears in the code, but it isn't in the error list)

Comment: Woops, you are right. I added UStaticMeshComponent to my answer as well. Sorry!

Comment: i got no more errors when i followed this as well. However, Unreal crashes when i tyr to compile this in live coding

Answer (score 1):

I have also run into this issue. 
I have completed the tutorial with some modifications.
Visual Studios 2019 14.24.28315
UE4 4.24

**MyPawn.h**

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "GameFramework/Character.h"
#include "MyPawn.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class HOWTO_PLAYERINPUT_API AMyPawn : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    AMyPawn();

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    virtual void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    USceneComponent* OurVisibleComponent;

    //Input functions
    void Move_XAxis(float AxisValue);
    void Move_YAxis(float AxisValue);
    void StartGrowing();
    void StopGrowing();

    //Input variables
    FVector CurrentVelocity;
    bool bGrowing;

};
```

**MyPawn.cpp**

```
// Fill out your copyright notice in the Description page of Project Settings.


#include "MyPawn.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"
#include "Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"

// Sets default values
AMyPawn::AMyPawn()
{
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    // Set this pawn to be controlled by the lowest-numbered player
    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;

    // Create a dummy root component we can attach things to.
    RootComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("RootComponent"));
    // Create a camera and a visible object
    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere)
    UCameraComponent* OurCamera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("OurCamera"));
    OurVisibleComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("OurVisibleComponent"));
    // Attach our camera and visible object to our root component. Offset and rotate the camera.
    OurCamera->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);
    OurCamera->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(-250.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f));
    OurCamera->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(-45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    OurVisibleComponent->SetupAttachment(OurCamera);
    OurVisibleComponent->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(268.0f, 0.0f, -14.14f));
    OurVisibleComponent->SetRelativeRotation(FRotator(45.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));


}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyPawn::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AMyPawn::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

    // Handle growing and shrinking based on our "Grow" action

    float CurrentScale = OurVisibleComponent->GetComponentScale().X;
    if (bGrowing)
    {
        // Grow to double size over the course of one second
        CurrentScale += DeltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        // Shrink half as fast as we grow
        CurrentScale -= (DeltaTime * 0.5f);
    }
    // Make sure we never drop below our starting size, or increase past double size.
    CurrentScale = FMath::Clamp(CurrentScale, 1.0f, 2.0f);
    OurVisibleComponent->SetWorldScale3D(FVector(CurrentScale));


    // Handle movement based on our "MoveX" and "MoveY" axes

    if (!CurrentVelocity.IsZero())
    {
        FVector NewLocation = GetActorLocation() + (CurrentVelocity * DeltaTime);
        SetActorLocation(NewLocation);
    }


}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void AMyPawn::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent)
{
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

    // Respond when our "Grow" key is pressed or released.
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Grow", IE_Pressed, this, &AMyPawn::StartGrowing);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAction("Grow", IE_Released, this, &AMyPawn::StopGrowing);

    // Respond every frame to the values of our two movement axes, "MoveX" and "MoveY".
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveX", this, &AMyPawn::Move_XAxis);
    PlayerInputComponent->BindAxis("MoveY", this, &AMyPawn::Move_YAxis);

}

void AMyPawn::Move_XAxis(float AxisValue)
{
    // Move at 100 units per second forward or backward
    CurrentVelocity.X = FMath::Clamp(AxisValue, -1.0f, 1.0f) * 100.0f;
}

void AMyPawn::Move_YAxis(float AxisValue)
{
    // Move at 100 units per second right or left
    CurrentVelocity.Y = FMath::Clamp(AxisValue, -1.0f, 1.0f) * 100.0f;
}

void AMyPawn::StartGrowing()
{
    bGrowing = true;
}

void AMyPawn::StopGrowing()
{
    bGrowing = false;
}
```

I Just find it insane that every time UE4 updates basically every tutorial goes to Hell.
*NOTE: I fumbled my way through completing this tutorial. I am meh at UE4 and did not take the time to "properly" write this code, so if anything is wrong style/convention wise, I'm sorry ;)